# Firebase orderByChild security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Given the firebase setup with the dinosaur example I would like to add a security rule for .read. If I add .read:true in the hierarchy like the following the query fails to provide any results.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dinosaurs": {
      "$dino": {
        ".read":true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I use the following the queries work as expected.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dinosaurs": {
        ".read":true
    }
  }
}
```

For my use case I need a setup more like the first example so that I can check each item for a condition before allowing a read to that item. To use the new orderByChild("property") style query however it would seems I have to allow access to the entire subtree. Is this the case?

Comment: That is the case, Tim. To search, one must have access to iterate/list the data in order to find the correct results. One approach would be to store searchable data separate from data you don't want users accessing. Then you could fetch a list of records and access the private data. A bit of a pain I realize.

Comment: Suggest turning the above comment into an answer...

Comment: When doing `orderByChild('property').equalTo('value')`, I would have thought it should be sufficient that the user both (a) has read access to the 'property' child for all records, and (b) has read access to the *matching* records (not necessarily all records). (Reasoning: the scanning and filtering happen on the server; the user never has access to the data.) Is there any particular reason why this isn't the case? It would be so much more convenient...

Comment: Also, I wish this was covered more clearly in the official documentation. :( @Kato